Can workers be the main cause of my node app crashing on production?
We are testing a Node.js backend on AWS, but our app keeps crashing after some use of certain tools that take a little bit long. We have in our implementation workers, but I don't know if they are causing this crashing. I've read that for asynchronous I/O operations the implementation of workers can make the application way more inefficient and slower. We have endpoints that connect to a python microservice, and they do some web scraping and return some json. This takes a little bit more than normal requests but not something out of this world, I'm talking of ms or even a second difference.
This problem has already been around a week since we deployed the backend. First, we thought it was the child process, because we called the python scripts via child process, so we decide to separate them implementing microservices. With our new microservices deployed we noticed an optimization in those scraping functions, but the main problem doesn't go. Our app still crashes at some point.
We are using EC2 free tier, and we just have access to 2 processor cores (2 workers). Help me see if I'm going on the right path to solve this problem. If we just use our backend for async requests (I/O operations) there's no need of workers and make this an inefficient solution. I think that as team we have a misunderstanding on the use of this workers and they don't represent any type of optimization on our backend requests.
This is our app.js, the core of the main microservice:
require('dotenv').config(); // Environment variables.
const cluster = require('cluster');
const { availableParallelism } = require('os');

// If the current process is the master process
if (cluster.isMaster) {
  // Get the number of available CPUs
  const numCPUs = availableParallelism();

  // Create workers according to the number of CPUs
  for (let i = 0; i < numCPUs; i++) {
    cluster.fork();
  }

  // Handle exit events of workers
  cluster.on('exit', (worker, code, signal) => {
    console.log(`Worker ${worker.process.pid} exited with code: ${code} and signal: ${signal}`);
    console.log('Creating a new worker...');
    cluster.fork(); // Create a new worker to replace the exited one
  });

  // Get the number of workers
  const numWorkers = Object.keys(cluster.workers).length;
  console.log(`Number of workers: ${numWorkers}`);
} else {
  // If the current process is a worker process
  const morgan = require('morgan');
  const express = require('express');
  const session = require('express-session');
  const compression = require('compression');
  const cors = require('cors');
  const hpp = require('hpp');
  const lusca = require('lusca');
  const helmet = require('helmet');
  const rateLimit = require('express-rate-limit');
  const config = require('./src/config');

  // ==== Route Imports ==== //
  // Health checker
  const healthRouter = require('./src/routes/healthCheck');

  // Initialize the App.
  const app = express();

  // Configure session and cookies.
  app.use(session(config.sessionConfig));

  // Global Variables.
  app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3001);

  // Global Configurations.
  app.use(morgan('dev')); // Dev displays info in a semi-condensed manner.
  app.use(cors(config.corsOptions)); // Implement and configure CORS.
  app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false })); // Middleware to decode form data (application/x-www-form-urlencoded).
  app.use(express.json()); // Middleware to parse JSON formatted request bodies.

  // Add hpp middleware.
  app.use(hpp());
  // Add express-rate-limit middleware.
  app.use(rateLimit(config.rateLimitConfig)); // Apply rate limit to all requests.
  // Add Lusca middleware.
  app.use(lusca(config.luscaOptions)); // Apply Lusca configurations.
  // Add Helmet middleware.
  app.use(helmet(config.helmetOptions)); // Apply Helmet configurations.

  // Add compression middleware.
  app.use(compression(config.compressionOptions.default));

  // ==== Routes ==== //

  // Enable proxy
  if (process.env.ENABLE_TRUST_PROXY) {
    app.enable('trust proxy');
  }

  // Check if the server is running.
  app.listen(app.get('port'), () => {
    console.log(`Worker ${process.pid} running on port: ${app.get('port')}`);
  });
}

NOTE: when I mean that our app crashes I mean our whole instance goes down (not just the container of our microservice), so that's why I think the implementation of workers are the problem. This was also the case before migrating to docker compose and to microservices.
